# Showing second popup when I close the first pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, popupwindow

I have a Popup and an input type button on it like below

```
         <input type="button" value="..." onclick="AddressPopup()"/>
```

and on my onclick function I show another pop up but it will close my first pop up

```
function AddressPopup() 
{
    page.popUp({
           path:  '/pages/Merchants/AddAddress.aspx?'      
           width: '400',
           height: '400',
           name: 'merch',
           title: 'title',
           onClose: AddressDone 
     });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is closing it or it is just getting super-imposed on the first one? Also, is the onClose function for the first popup being executed? One more things, try to cancel the propagation of the event and see what happens?

Comment: by clicking on button AddressPopup will be open and my first pop up will be close , and yes this on close will be execute.

Comment: @Sean12 i added return false ' <input type="button" value="..." onclick="AddressPopup() return false;"/>' but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code solved my problem :

```
  function AddressPopup() {
        $('#AddressDiv').dialog({
            title:'title',
            maxWidth: 400,
            width: 400,
            height: 500,
            modal: true,
            close: function () {
                var selectedObj = page.object();

                $('#<%= txtADDRESS.ClientID %>').val(selectedObj);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting z-index CSS property for the popup classes[or ID(#)].

```
.other-pop {
   z-index: 9997;
}

.address-pop {
   z-index: 9998; // This will come above `other-pop`
}
```

## Edit:

@MAriiiyAM - Check this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aravinth/k25HU/6/) and see if that is your requirement.

Comment: i couldn't find my problem but by using jquery dialog problem solved , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're comfortable  using Jquery,you can simply use hide() and show() functions on the onclick event.

```
 .on('button', function() {
                    $('#id_of_1st_popup').show();
                    $('#id_of_2nd_popup').show();
                })
```

If you wish you hide either of them while one is open :-

```
.on('button', function() {
                    $('#id_of_1st_popup').show();
                    $('#id_of_2nd_popup').hide();
                })
```